# how to draw svg line on canvas in sequence?

Tags: android, svg, android-canvas, draw

the idea is, i want to make animated kanji letter (in sequence) like this project [HTML5 Stroke Animation](http://nippongrammar.appspot.com/). And my problem is, when i call onDraw method my canvas just draw simultaneously. I couldn't find much info about it on the internet, so any clue would be much appreciated if you have already come across the same situation.
here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView txt;
private SvgPathParser svgPathParser;
private PathView pathView;
private String sPath =
        "M32.49,17.39c0.14,1.08,0.24,2.44-0.12,3.77c-2.29,8.41-11.14,24.16-21.81,35.56" +
                "|M25.03,42c0.59,0.61,0.76,1.97,0.76,3.23c0,10.08,0.08,28.85,0,40.77c-0.02,3.48-0.04,6.4-0.04,8.38" +
                "|M55.1,14.25c0.05,0.65,0.16,1.69-0.09,2.6c-1.55,5.6-8.51,16.02-17.36,24.43" +
                "|M53.88,27.02c0.94,0.18,3.7,0.29,4.62,0.18c4.47-0.52,18.49-2.45,26.44-3.62c2.43-0.36,4.03-0.45,6.45-0.17" +
                "|M52.82,39.44c1.03,0.85,1.4,3.75,0.72,5.89c-3.37,10.67-6.4,19.7-11.35,30.04c-1.45,3.03-0.49,4.25,1.47,4.33c10.84,0.43,18.96,1.05,29.44,3.78c5.98,1.55,12.27,4.02,17.89,7.93" +
                "|M54.69,42.07c6.68-0.95,22.21-3.14,26.69-3.43c3.45-0.22,4.43,1.81,4.14,4.54c-1.33,12.48-5.94,37.8-10.23,47.46c-2.3,5.17-4.97,4.12-7.54,1.33" +
                "|M68.32,43.35c0.45,0.88,0.63,2.39,0.13,4.22c-2.32,8.56-7.53,25.28-10.01,32.34" +
                "|M32.07,61.64c3.43,0.61,5.94,0.44,8.42,0.17c12.25-1.31,31.7-3.07,49-3.92c2.76-0.14,5.75-0.41,8.43,0.38";
String[] arrayPath = sPath.split("\\|");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new PathView(this));


}


private Path path(String sPath) throws ParseException {

    svgPathParser = new SvgPathParser();
    return svgPathParser.parsePath(sPath);
}


public class PathView extends View {
    Path path;
    Paint paint;
    List<Path> paths;
    float length;

    public PathView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PathView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PathView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void init() {
        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        path = new Path();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayPath.length; i++) {
            try {
                paths.add(path(arrayPath[i]));
                //     path = );
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // Measure the path
        for (Path path : paths) {
            this.path = path;
            PathMeasure measure = new PathMeasure(path, false);
            length = measure.getLength();
            float[] intervals = new float[]{length, length};
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(PathView.this, "phase", 1.0f, 0.0f);
            animator.setDuration(2000);
            animator.start();
        }

    }

    //is called by animtor object
    public void setPhase(float phase) {
        Log.d("pathview", "setPhase called with:" + String.valueOf(phase));
        paint.setPathEffect(createPathEffect(length, phase, 0.0f));
        invalidate();//will calll onDraw
    }

    private PathEffect createPathEffect(float pathLength, float phase, float offset) {
        return new DashPathEffect(new float[]{pathLength, pathLength},
                Math.max(phase * pathLength, offset));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);
        for (Path path : paths) {
            this.path = path;
            c.drawPath(path, paint);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: use `android.os.Handler` and any of "delayed" methods

Comment: does not work, my UI got sluggish and my path still drawn in simultaneously..

Comment: `android.os.Handler` does work,  it is used in hundreds of places inside android platform

Comment: could you make example code how to do that please ..? cz my code does not work. im new on android development.. i will very appreciate it..